# Unity: make one word draggable in a text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text

I'm searching for a way to make only one word in a TextMeshPro UI object draggable. I want my player to drop this word on another part of the screen to win the level.

One solution could be adding the word as a separate object to my UI, but that could easily mess things up since we have so many mobile devices with different screen sizes.

So what do you suggest? is there really any way?

I searched all over the web for a solution. But there was no one answering it. So I thought maybe I should be the one asking. Any solution could seriously help me and all the others searching for something like this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't want to deal with kind of 3D object that appears from UI because, as you mentioned, it would be a headache to match its size with UI, so we skip that entirely. The remainder is really goes in two ways, one is dumb and other is clever:

1. The dumb approach is to make the word to appear as a separate object in between other text objects in a normal UI layout (you still should deal with correct paddings to hide it in the line of text). The trick is that on click we are storing the RectTransform values to clone the word on the same Canvas, but not attached to any layout, thus player will be able to drag it around. The original word should not be disabled to not shift the layout, instead just make the color transparent.
2. The clever way, also more flexible: try to make a world-space TMP_Text that is accurately matching the Canvas version of it. Since TMP components are universal, it should be achievable. If you managed to make world-text to repeat the shape after the UI text and you happy with the result, do the rest of the trick as above. The difference is that the world text could be translated and scaled as you wish, not restricted to a 2D plane of the Canvas.